# Set persistent notification for certain app

Tags: 18.04, skype, notification

**The problem**: I recieve skype messages while afk and I don't notice the little orange dot in the trayicon when I'm back.

**The question**: I'd like to make Skype's notifications persistent on screen (until I dismiss them) so that I don't miss them. Is it possible to make notifications sent by apps persistent?

**I'm on**: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using Skypeforlinux (Skype version 8.22.0.2)

*Any other solution to make me notice skype's notifications (like make blinking dock icon) is welcomed*

P.S. it is not a duplicate of older similar question since those refer to a different skype version that didn't used the system notification by default. Now it does and it isn't possible to customize it anymore (I was used to setup a messagebox whenever a message from a new chat was sent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [Grown-up notifications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1335/grown-up-notifications/)
combined with [Permanent notifications](http://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications) extensions to solve your same problem. (:

Comment: I tried "Grown-up notifications" but system notification still disappear after some seconds as usual.
What do you mean by "WhatsApp wrapper with notifications disappearing in 1-2 seconds" you wrap skype's notifications?

Comment: @LucaRicci did you try combining Grown-up notifications with Permanent notifications? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/
Anyway no, it's only a WhatsApp application, that keep notifications disappearing immediately, but with the linked extension I solved the problem. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: it worked. The combination of both the exetensions did the trick. Thanks. Maybe you can update the answer adding the permanent-notification extension you cited in the comment? I'll accept the answer in the meantime.

Comment: @LucaRicci I'm glad it worked. (:
I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Grown-up notifications is no longer supported on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

You can have persistent notifications  simply by turning on "permanent notifications" in Tweaks application.

To install tweaks:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

To install the gnome extensions:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then press Super key, search for tweaks & turn on permanent notifications option in it.

For detailed procedure to install tweaks: https://linuxhint.com/installing_gnome_extensions_ubuntu/